# Not charging while laptop in use otherwise charging

Tags: motherboard, charging, runtime-error, hp-laptop

My laptop brand and number is **(HP-ac124TX)**, laptop is charging well **(orange light)** when the laptop is not turned on and as soon as I'm turning it on it is not charging **(white light)**, as matter of fact the following error is also coming when I'm turning on the laptop **(IDK whether it is related to my problem or not)**

**Error :-**

> Product Information not valid
> The following product information programmed into the system board Is missing or invalid.
> Board (0OA)- System Board CT Number
> ENTER - Continue Startup
> For more information, please visit: [www.hp.com/go/techcenter/startup](http://www.hp.com/go/techcenter/startup)

I've researched the error and it appears because of a changed motherboard or some components, but I've not changed the motherboard.

So my question is?

1. What should I do?
2. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  The spelling mistakes this question difficult to read.  Some of the error messages have words that are not spelled correctly.

Comment: @Ramhound I've edited the error messege successfully.

Answer (score 0):

> **What should I do?**

The advice you refer to says

> System Board (00A) Product Information Not Valid Error
>
> 1. You might see this message after the system board is replaced. The message indicates that the serial number was not entered, or was entered incorrectly, after replacing the system board or other component.
> 2. Contact HP to service the computer. The procedure must be performed at an HP authorized service center.
>    Go to HP PCs - System Board (00A) Error Appears on a Black Screen for further assistance.

So you could contact HP to get the fault repaired.

It is possible that your power supply is not working correctly and is not able to provide as much current as it should. There may have been some event that caused both this and the motherboard issue. It is hard to know if they are related. I doubt that replacing the power supply will fix both issues but it might be worth trying - only you can judge if this makes sense for you financially. If the computer is old you might just live with the problems. Just make sure all important data is backed up regularly to offline media or cloud storage etc and check the backups are able to be restored on another PC.

Comment: Yes, indeed I will take it to service center. I've checked the powersupply by multi meter and it gives the output it is supposed to give. Yes, it's an old pc and I've even tried resetting the windows but the problem persisted. The problem is with the hardware I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching and the problem is "overclocking  of CPU" and frequently you get error of Windows 10 collecting sample of errors.
So, the solution is to shutdown once the windows, before using it. The light shomehow remains the same but you get a charging icon as (plugged in), not (charging), but somehow the battery remains same. It worked for me !!